# UILabel not making two lines

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a bunch of UILabels but the following UILabel (lastMessage) is only showing one line. It's supposed to truncate by tail, but there are no ellipses meaning the second line simply does not exist. Additionally, the dateTime UILabel isn't showing either. Could this have something to do with my autolayout constraints? My code for UITableViewCell:

```
let nameLabel = UILabel()
    let lastMessage = UILabel()
    let profileImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blankAvatar"))
    let dateTime = UILabel()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: aDecoder)}
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        nameLabel.tintColor = .label
        nameLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dateTime.numberOfLines = 1
        dateTime.tintColor = .label
        dateTime.text = "7:03"
        dateTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lastMessage.numberOfLines = 2
        lastMessage.tintColor = .lightGray
        lastMessage.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        lastMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(lastMessage)
        contentView.addSubview(dateTime)
        contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 3)
        let lg = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 6),
            nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateTime.leadingAnchor),
            nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastMessage.topAnchor, constant: 6),
            dateTime.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            dateTime.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            dateTime.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastMessage.topAnchor),

            lastMessage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 6),
            lastMessage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            lastMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

This was in the init. Thanks!

Edit: The UITableViewCell was not the issue. I had embedded the table inside a horizontal UIScrollView ([repo](https://github.com/YoomamaFTW/infinite-view-controllers)), but my auto layout constraints for the table was top, leading, trailing, and bottom anchor. I switched it to be all but trailing anchor so that I could use a width anchor instead with a constant of the `view.bounds.width`.

Comment: add the screenshot of result you got

Comment: Oh sorry, one moment @DilanAnuruddha there seems to be some other confounding factor in play... It's currently in a UIScrollView that moves horizontally, but when I remove the scroll view, the problem is gone...? I guess let me debug it a little further.

Comment: @Yoomama check my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code :

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

And don't give `height constraint` to your `label`. So, it can auto resize itself according to `text height`.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi, the cell was apparently fine. It was some other configuration I had done that messed up my UITableView since I had made an infinite view controller app with UIScrollView.

Comment: Did you try my answer ? @Yoomama

Comment: I didn't need to. It was a completely different issue regarding a different configuration. You can read my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Update you code by this:

```
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```